# How can I set some checkboxes to selected upon the first loading of the form?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form with checkboxes.

```
$form['my_checkboxes'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => ['1' => 'one', '2' => 'two', '3' => 'three'],
];
```

And for example, I want to option '1' is selected upon form was loaded.

Could you clarify me, how can I set some checkboxes to selected upon the first loading of the form ?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the solution in the examples module.

Comment: You can set a default value in those fields. So you built that form programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `#default_value`:

```
$form['my_checkboxes'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => ['1' => 'one', '2' => 'two', '3' => 'three'],
  '#default_value' => [1, 2],
];
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I've just figured it out experimentally.